# ASP.NET Error: Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: asp.net, scalar

I know I'm obviously missing / have improperly declared a variable but I'm not quite sure how to fix that. I am getting this error when ever I click "btnUpdate" to update the information in the database (based on whats in the text fields). I've posted the code below for review, thanks for the help!

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs"     Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

<div class="floater">
<h3>Books</h3>
<asp:DropDownList
    id="DropDownList_Books"
    DataSourceId="srcBooks"
    DataTextField="Title"
    DataValueField="Id"
    Runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="View Detials" Width="106px" 
        onclick="btnSelect_Click" />
</div>

<asp:GridView
    id="grdBooks"
    DataSourceID="srcBooks_Description"
    Runat="server" Visible="False" />

    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" onclick="btnEdit_Click" Text="Edit" />

</div>

<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" onclick="btnCancel_Click" 
    style="z-index: 1; left: 464px; top: 153px; position: absolute; height: 26px" 
    Text="Cancel" Visible="False" />

<asp:FormView
    id="frmEditBook"
    DataKeyNames="Cat_Id"
    DataSourceId="srcBooks_Description"
    DefaultMode="Edit"
    Runat="server" Visible="False" 
    style="z-index: 1; left: 391px; top: 87px; position: absolute; height: 111px; width: 206px">
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label
        id="lblTitle"
        Text="Title:"
        AssociatedControlID="txtTitle"
        Runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox
        id="txtTitle"
        Text='<%#Bind("Title")%>'
        Runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label
        id="lblDescription"
        Text="Description:"
        AssociatedControlID="txtDescription"
        Runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox
        id="txtDescription"
        Text='<%#Bind("Description")%>'
        Runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button
        id="btnUpdate"
        Text="Update"
        CommandName="Update"
        Runat="server" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="srcBooks" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="Data Source=&quot;ebiz.isy.vcu.edu, 14330&quot;;Initial Catalog=spring12u08;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Spring12u08;Password=INFO451u08" 
    onselecting="srcBooks_Selecting" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT Title,Id FROM PARTIN_ID">

</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="srcBooks_Description" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="Data Source=&quot;ebiz.isy.vcu.edu, 14330&quot;;Initial Catalog=spring12u08;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Spring12u08;Password=INFO451u08" 
    onselecting="srcBooks_Selecting" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM PARTIN_INFO WHERE Cat_ID=@Id" UpdateCommand="UPDATE PARTIN_INFO SET Title=@Title,
        Description=@Description WHERE Cat_Id=@Id">
<SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter
            Name="Id"
            Type="int32"                
            ControlID="DropDownList_Books" />
    </SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Updated Code with new error: Could not find control 'txtTitle' in ControlParameter 'Title'.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

<div class="floater">
<h3>Books</h3>
<asp:DropDownList
    id="DropDownList_Books"
    DataSourceId="srcBooks"
    DataTextField="Title"
    DataValueField="Id"
    Runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="View Detials" Width="106px" 
        onclick="btnSelect_Click" />
</div>

<asp:GridView
    id="grdBooks"
    DataSourceID="srcBooks_Description"
    Runat="server" Visible="False" />

    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" onclick="btnEdit_Click" Text="Edit" />

</div>

<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" onclick="btnCancel_Click" 
    style="z-index: 1; left: 464px; top: 153px; position: absolute; height: 26px" 
    Text="Cancel" Visible="False" />

<asp:FormView
    id="frmEditBook"
    DataKeyNames="Cat_Id"
    DataSourceId="srcBooks_Description"
    DefaultMode="Edit"
    Runat="server" Visible="False" 

    style="z-index: 1; left: 391px; top: 87px; position: absolute; height: 111px; width: 206px" >
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label
        id="lblTitle"
        Text="Title:"
        AssociatedControlID="txtTitle"
        Runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox
        id="txtTitle"
        Text='<%#Bind("Title")%>'
        Runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label
        id="lblDescription"
        Text="Description:"
        AssociatedControlID="txtDescription"
        Runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox
        id="txtDescription"
        Text='<%#Bind("Description")%>'
        Runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button
        id="btnUpdate"
        Text="Update"
        CommandName="Update"
        Runat="server" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="srcBooks" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="Data Source=&quot;ebiz.isy.vcu.edu, 14330&quot;;Initial Catalog=spring12u08;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Spring12u08;Password=INFO451u08" 
    onselecting="srcBooks_Selecting" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT Title,Id FROM PARTIN_ID">

</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="srcBooks_Description" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="Data Source=&quot;ebiz.isy.vcu.edu, 14330&quot;;Initial Catalog=spring12u08;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Spring12u08;Password=INFO451u08" 
    onselecting="srcBooks_Selecting" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM PARTIN_INFO WHERE Cat_ID=@Id" UpdateCommand="UPDATE PARTIN_INFO SET Title=@Title,
        Description=@Description WHERE Cat_Id=@Id">
<SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter
            Name="Id"
            Type="int32"                
            ControlID="DropDownList_Books"
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
     <UpdateParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter Name="Title" ControlId="txtTitle" PropertyName="Text"/>
          <asp:ControlParameter Name="Description" ControlId="txtDescription" PropertyName="Text"/>
          <asp:ControlParameter Name="Id" ControlId="DropDownList_Books" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
      </UpdateParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>

</form>
```

Also code behind:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void srcBooks_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grdBooks.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmEditBook.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmEditBook.Visible = true;
        btnCancel.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            srcBooks_Description.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {
            // Handle the Exception.
        }
    }






    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code behind also.

Comment: The asp:ControlParameter also needs to specify `PropertyName="Value"`.

Comment: `srcBooks_Description` also needs `UpdateParameters`.

Comment: The problem is in your SQL vs. the parameters you're passing to it.

Comment: Please see my edits, examples or code fixes are welcome I'm very new to ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.  I changed all the field names in the original table to one word or multiple words separated by an underline, such as card_number, changed the select and update statements and it worked fine.